# Backtick on an Italian MacBook Pro's keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I have a MacBook Pro with an Italian keyboard, and I need to type <kbd>`</kbd> character in a bash script. But I cannot get the right key sequence. How can I type this character?

Comment: When in doubt, use Ukelele: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an international english keyboard, it's to the right of the left shift key.

If you have neither US nor Int'l English keyboard layout, now would be a good time to tell us what you have instead. Or, open `System Preferences`, click on `Language & Text`, `Input Sources` (*), then check both `Keyboard & Character Viewer` and `Show Input menu in menu bar`. Now you can open the `Keyboard Viewer` from the new menu bar item and look up all characters. Press Shift and/or Option to see what characters are written when those modifiers are pressed.

*: This is also where you would look up your keyboard layout.

If your keyboard layout doesn't have this key at all, in Character Palette you can find it searching for GRAVE ACCENT.

Comment: I have italian keyboard and cannot see that key

Comment: @Cris Wow, that is one funky layout. Backtick is on the same key as 9 in the number row, you need to press alt (not shift though). It is only available as a deadkey, so you need to press Space afterwards. Otherwise, e.g. an `e` would be transformed to an `è`.

Comment: @Cris if you use "Italian Pro" layout instead of "Italian" (see my answer on how to find this out), a non-deadkey version is between `Esc` and `Tab`, but you need to press `Option/Alt` to get it.

Answer (score 25):

I think the real answer is pretty hidden so i will state it clearly for the next users:

The **backtick** is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> on the **Italian keyboard layout** of a Mac OS X 10.7.5.

It's also available as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd> (dead key).

Comment: MacBook now, instead of `Alt` has `option` key, so e.g. in Italian Keyboard is: `option` + \

Answer (score 3):

That's an accent and is normally found on the same as the tilde key (right under esc).

<sup>Note that this is **not** a Mac keyboard, but the placement should be the same.</sup>

[image: accent key placement]

Comment: I have a MacBookPro and can confirm that the placement IS the same. Photo http://images.apple.com/macbookpro/images/overview-gallery2-20090828.png

Comment: That's not an Italian keyboard though

Answer (score 3):

on the Italian Mac keyboard you just press `option + 9`

Look I'm doing it right now ````````  xD

Comment: A previous answer says same thing.

Answer (score 0):

On an Italian Mac keyboard (QWERTY, MacBook Pro), it's:

⌥  + ⇧ + 1.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here because `option` + `\` does work in terminal, but not in other programs (like Intellij or Pycharm),

I just found out that with the new release of Intellij, they added a new keymap (`option` + `\`) to enable AI Assistant auto complete.

So, if you want to have backtick again, remember to disable that shortcut or use `option` + `9`